# Enum based custom attribute that could be set atop some C#.Net class property. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

Is it possible to have an enum based custom attribute that could be set atop some class property in C#.Net?

Example: I am trying to do the following:

```
[AutoUpdateEnumParam(new AutoUpdateParamOption[] 
          { new AutoUpdateParamOption("Offline", 0), 
            new AutoUpdateParamOption("Online", 1), 
            new AutoUpdateParamOption("Deactivated", 2), 
            new AutoUpdateParamOption("Reset", 3), 
            new AutoUpdateParamOption("Removed", 4) })]
public int Status
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

When I compile the project, it gives me following error:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

[UPDATE]
Somebody asked me, how I have defined my AutoUpdateEnumParam class. Here it is:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class AutoUpdateEnumParam : Attribute
    {
        AutoUpdateParamOption[] _paramEnum;

        public AutoUpdateParamOption[] Options
        {
            get
            {
                return _paramEnum;
            }
        }

        public AutoUpdateEnumParam(AutoUpdateParamOption[] paramEnum)
        {
            this._paramEnum = paramEnum;
        }
    }

    public class AutoUpdateParamOption
    {
        private string _text = string.Empty;
        private object _value = null;
        private string _type = "string";

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return _text;
            }
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }

        public string ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                return _type;
            }
        }

        public AutoUpdateParamOption(string text, int value)
        {
            this._text = text;
            this._value = value;
            this._type = "int";
        }

        public AutoUpdateParamOption(string text, double value)
        {
            this._text = text;
            this._value = value;
            this._type = "double";
        }

        public AutoUpdateParamOption(string text, string value)
        {
            this._text = text;
            this._value = value;
            this._type = "string";
        }

        public AutoUpdateParamOption(string text, bool value)
        {
            this._text = text;
            this._value = value;
            this._type = "boolean";
        }
    }
```

Comment: An attribute has to derive from `System.Attribute`-class, so an enumeration won´t work. Anyway How does your `AutoUpdateEnumParam` is defined?

Comment: If I understand the problem right you can present value as string (e.g. using json-like syntax): `[MyAttribute("Offline:0,Online:1,...")]` which you can parse in attribute constructor to generate (deserialize?) needed values. This is not very usable. Perhaps array of strings will work (if it doesn't, then constructor overload with varied number of `string` arguments should do), then you can define constants to use use with attribute (will have intellisense support), something like `[MyAttribute(Offline,Online, ...)]`.

Comment: @Sinatr I have already resorted to that thing :) But my question is still there that the thing mentioned in my question, can it be done?

Comment: Attribute arguments are strictly limited, the compiler needs to be able to evaluate them at compile time so the values can be embedded in the metadata.  So anything like a *new* statement is not impossible, that is code.